how to mask specific function or suggestion in Rstudio autocomplete?
Only a cosmetic topic here but which would save time when typing and specifically for completion.
When I type "readrd" in RStudio it always suggest read_rds() from readr first, instead of base readRDS() that I want.
I want to remove the function read_rds() from my environnement, as I never use it, without removing the whole readr package.
I have the same kind of issue with geom_line() where I get a suggestion for "GeomLine" which is this time an object instead of geom_line(). I don't even know where is GeomLine from.
Quite a specific question but I think mastering objects/functions masking could be of help in other situations such as packages conflicts.
I was not able to remove a specific object inside of a loaded package with either rm(read_rds) or detach(read_rds).
library(readr)
rm(read_rds) # doesn't work
detach(read_rds) # doesn't work


You can do e.g. library(readr, exclude = "read_rds") to exclude specific functions from being loaded.

Thank you very much ! This did the trick. To give a bit more information, as i was loading tidyverse which includes readr, i had to replace this import with 1 import for each package inside tidyverse, then add the exclude option for readr.

You won't need to import each package individually if you load the packages with exclusions first.  i.e. do library(readr, exclude = "read_rds"); library(tidyverse).

You can create a snippet for the text readrd which should be the first option for autocomplete (at least it is for me).
Go to Tools>Global Options..., select Code and in the Edit tab, the last item has 'Enable code snippets' and 'Edit Snippets...'. Click 'Edit Snippets' and add the following to the list:
snippet readrd
  readRDS(${0})


Make sure it is a TAB at the start of the readRDS(${0}) line. And make sure the following line is completely empty - no spaces or tabs.
Save and exit. (Make sure 'Enable code snippets' is checked.) Now readRDS should be the first option for autocomplete as you type 'readrd'.

This is an interesting workaround, thank you. I used Lotus' answer as it seems to be the "clean" way of doing this : snippets have to be created with a specific abbreviation, and will tend to overload the autosuggest pane if I have a lot of them. But in specific situations it might be the best option.
